# How to uninstall Steam Remote Play?

Tags: steam

I installed Steam a while back trying to play some games. Now that I'm taking classes again, I uninstalled it and let my brother uses my account so we don't have to buy the same games twice. The problem is that from time to time, I still see a Steam popup that says `Steam Remote Play is n...`. I tried clicking on it but it doesn't do anything. How do I uninstall that Steam Remote Play popup?

Comment: It is a Gnome notification or a browser notification? On what version of Ubuntu are you on? You can disable Steam Play by going to Steam>[Steam]>[Settings]>[Steam Play] and untick the abilitation

Comment: I'm on 18.04 and it's a Gnome notification. I can't disable it since I already uninstalled Steam in the terminal.

Comment: What is the icon of the notification, is it the Steam icon? Also, post the output of `ps axu | grep steam`.

Comment: Add also the output of `sudo updatedb && locate -c steam` please

Comment: Yeah the notification pops up from the bottom right with the Steam logo. Output of first command is `kingle   25180  0.0  0.0  21532  1060 pts/0    S+   17:00   0:00 grep --color=auto steam`. Output of second command is `15858`

Comment: The second commands says that you still have 15858 steam files on your computer, so probably you forgot to remove some of them. The first command says that there is no "steam" process still running in the background. I need you to paste on a pastebin the **full** output of `locate steam` (it's going to be 15858 lines) and post the link to it here

Comment: Took me a while, had to figure out how to export terminal output and split files so it fits pastebin 512KB limit. Here are the links: [Paste 1](https://pastebin.com/Rm2uWv06), [Paste 2](https://pastebin.com/pEttdCmv), [Paste 3](https://pastebin.com/mCFd5hsW).

Comment: Good news: almost everything is in your home folder. To remove this residue from the steam configurations, just remove the hidden .steam folder: `rm -r ~/.steam` (**no** `sudo` needed, **don't** use it, just type the command as it is)

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought using `sudo apt remove steam` was enough. Not sure why Steam needs to create a hidden folder and hoard a ton of files inside.

Comment: Like every other program on Linux, steam saves all that it needs in your personal folder, so that another user will not have access to your data. Please let me know if that suffices or not.

Comment: It's been working great. No issue since I removed that folder.

Comment: Great! I will write it as an answer to accept then, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this residue from the steam configurations, just remove the hidden .steam folder:

```
rm -r ~/.steam
```

(**no `sudo` needed**, don't use it, just type the command as it is)